# Constant solutions and uniquenss of solutions theorem for IVPs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

What role do constant solutions play in the existance and uniqueness theorem? For instance, consider the IVP

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x$$ $$ y(0) = 0 $$

Clearly, this IVP has a solution in the form of $y =\frac{x^2}{2}$. Now the existance and uniqueness theorem tells us that for $$\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x,y)$$ if $f(x,y)$ and $\frac{df}{dy}$ are both continuous around $(x_0,y_0)$ then there will be only one solution in some interval around $x_0$. And since both $x$ and the constant function $\frac{df}{dy} = 0$ are continuous around $(0,0)$ it should be unique. But the constant function $y = 0$ is also a solution if $\frac{dy}{dx} = x = 0$

Meaning, that $y = 0$ solves the IVP at that one point (a rather weak solution, I admit). But doesn't this contradict the uniqueness theorem of IVPs, since we in effect have two different functions that solve the same IVP?

Comment: But it is not a solution for the IVP in the interval around. It only works for one point.

Comment: @user3313320 Yes, and looking up definitions of IVPs we do actually require that it solves over an interval. I am assuming that degenerate intervals such as [x,x] don't count in this endevour. In fact excluding them would probably avoid a lot of these headaches. Thanks dude, that got my mind on the right track!

Comment: Indeed, both solutions are the same at the one point at which they both satisfy the IVP, so you still have uniqueness.

Comment: If you look at the proof you wil see that you get a symmetric  interval around $x_o$ ver which the solution exists and is unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zero function does not satisfy that differential equation, since

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \neq x$$

on all open intervals that include $0$.

It satisfies the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} = y$$

but that's a whole other story...

Comment: Yes, indeed it seems that solutions are defined in terms of functions that solve on intervals, and like I mentioned in the comment on the OP I assume degenerate cases, ie single points, don't count as such. Thanks a lot for your time!